# Angular 4 typescript get array from promise

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

I'm getting troubles storing data from a returned promise.

To ensure that the value I want has indeed been returned I log it like this.

```
private fetchData() {
    this._movieFranchiseService.getHighestGrossingFilmFranchises()
      .then((franchises: FilmFranchise[]) => {
        console.log(franchises)
    });
}
```

But now I want to store it.

```
private franchises: FilmFranchise[] = [];

private fetchData() {
    this._movieFranchiseService.getHighestGrossingFilmFranchises()
      .then((franchises: FilmFranchise[]) => this.franchises = franchises);
    console.log(this.franchises);
}
```

All I get with this code is an empty array. So why isn't `this.franchises` assigned correctly ?

Additional model, mock and service

```
export class FilmFranchise {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  revenue: number; // Revenue in billion U.S dollars
}

export var FRANCHISES: FilmFranchise[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Marvel Cinematic Universe', revenue: 13.47 },
    { id: 2, name: 'J.K Rowling\'s Wizarding World', revenue: 8.54 },
    { id: 3, name: 'Star Wars', revenue: 7.52 },
    { id: 4, name: 'James Bond', revenue: 7.04 },
    { id: 5, name: 'Middle Earth', revenue: 5.88 }
];

public getHighestGrossingFilmFranchises() {
  return Promise.resolve(FRANCHISES);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you make the change I suggested in my answer below? Even with the change the code you have above is still going to always *log* an empty array.

Comment: I did and the log is indeed correct. I understand that I can't access it right away because it is not asynchronous. Now what can I do to be able to access it ?

Comment: I'll expand my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

I would guess that the problem is with your logging, not your data access.

If the get method you are using is asynchronous, you cannot log it's value immediately after the call. You have to do it *within* the callback.

Something like this:

```
private fetchData() {
    this._movieFranchiseService.getHighestGrossingFilmFranchises()
      .then((franchises: FilmFranchise[]) => {
          this.franchises = franchises);
          console.log(this.franchises);
       }
}
```

I changed the single line callback to a multi-line callback by adding another set of braces. Now both lines are within the callback.

**EDIT**

A few things about managing data from an Http call.

As you know, Http is asynchronous, so you have to wait for the data to be returned in the response before you can use it.

Angular most often uses Observables (not promises) to work with http data.

A service will retrieve the data and return the Observable.

Any component that needs to work with the data will subscribe to the Observable. The component can then work with that data in the function provided to the subscribe method.

As an example, here is a simple "movie" service:

```
getMovies(): Observable<IMovie[]> {
    return this.http.get<IMovie[]>(this.moviesUrl);
}
```

It returns an observable.

Here is a simple component that uses the service:

```
ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.movieService.getMovies()
        .subscribe(
            (movies: IMovie[]) => {
                this.movies = movies;
                this.filteredMovies = this.performFilter(this.listFilter);
            },
            (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

Any code that we want to work with the data is within the subscribe.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not sure how this can help me. Array `this.franchises` is still empty if I try to log it later.

Comment: I think you need to read this carefully and make sure you are calling it right. I'm able to also log the `this.franchises`

Comment: I understand the synchronicity issue and the need of Observable. Thanks for the edit.